# Static AppSettings Wrapper class in Console App

Tags: c#, .net

Have a console app with this littler app settings wrapper. Idea being that it wraps my settings for ease of access and maintenance. This little wrapper is used through the app. Getting a "value cannot be null" error and cannot figure out why. If I called the GetAppSetting method directly I get my value. If I call the property that then calls the GetAppSetting method I get the error. What gives!

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // gets value from appSettings
    var apiZipFilePath = AppSettingsHelper.GetAppSetting("apiZipFilePath");

    // bombs, Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: String
    var apiZipFilePath2 = AppSettingsHelper.ApiZipFilePath;
}


public static class AppSettingsHelper
{
    public static string GetAppSetting(string appKey)
    {
        return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[appKey];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Path to api back up
    /// </summary>
    public static string ApiZipFilePath = GetAppSetting("apiZipFilePath");
}
```

Comment: That's a field not a property. Make it a property.

Comment: I copied the code exactly as you have it into a unit test and it compiles and passes test with no issue.

Comment: You're right. I pulled the snip into a freshy-fresh console app. Worked as expected. Something else is causing this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Was due to null result getting from appsetting. didn't exist. Worked out little method for this issue public static T GetAppSetting<T>(string key)
        {
            if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key] != null)
            {
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key], typeof(T));
            }
            return default(T);
        }